# Properly generate convex hull and get plane equations

Tags: computational-geometry, z3, cplex, cgal, convex-hull

I am completely new to Computational Geometry. I want to generate convex hull of a set of points and then get plane equations for the generated convex polyhedron so that I can check inclusion/exclusion of points. I have followed the docs and tried the whole procedure probably a dozen times but there is always some issue. Maybe I'm missing some subtle point here. The whole procedure is as follows. I have the following plot, generated in Mathematica.

[image: A plot, generated from a secret function]

I want to include every point that is on the plot inside a convex hull. So I take all the points lying on all corners of both planes and the origin (Maybe that's the problem. Maybe there is a way to properly choose points so that all points on the plot are covered). The points for this specific plot are as follows. Note that the points are generated using infinite precision so they are exact values.

```
pts = {
  {-24298771/25000000000,-223461425901/50000000000,0},
  {11285077/10000000000,-223461425901/50000000000,0},
  {-24298771/25000000000,0,0},
  {-24298771/25000000000,-11285077/10000000000,0},
  {-24298771/25000000000,120551411529/25000000000,-24298771/25000000000},
  {11285077/10000000000,120551411529/25000000000,11285077/10000000000},
  {11285077/10000000000,0,11285077/10000000000},
  {-24298771/25000000000,24298771/25000000000,-24298771/25000000000},
  {0,0,0}
};
```

Then, I use the following CGAL program to generate the convex hull and plane equations. Again, trying to keep things in infinite precision.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Side_of_triangle_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iomanip>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron_3;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef Kernel::Plane_3 Plane_3;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector_3;
typedef CGAL::Side_of_triangle_mesh<Polyhedron_3, Kernel> Point_inside;

struct Plane_equation {
    template <class Facet>
    typename Facet::Plane_3 operator()( Facet& f) {
    typename Facet::Halfedge_handle h = f.halfedge();
    typedef typename Facet::Plane_3  Plane;
    return Plane( h->vertex()->point(),
              h->next()->vertex()->point(),
              h->next()->next()->vertex()->point());
    }
};

Point_3 create_point(std::vector<std::string> points) {
  auto x = points[0], y = points[1], z = points[2];
  Point_3 p;
  std::istringstream input(x + " " + y + " " + z);
  input >> p;
  return p;
}

std::vector<std::string> create_coords_from_line(std::string line) {
  std::vector<std::string> points;
  std::istringstream stream(line);
  std::string pt;
  getline(stream, pt, ' ');
  points.push_back(pt);
  getline(stream, pt, ' ');
  points.push_back(pt);
  getline(stream, pt);
  points.push_back(pt);
  return points;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<Point_3> points;
    std::string line;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
      getline(std::cin, line);
      points.push_back(create_point(create_coords_from_line(line)));
    }

    Polyhedron_3 poly;
    CGAL::convex_hull_3(points.begin(), points.end(), poly);
    // CGAL::draw(poly);
    std::transform(poly.facets_begin(), poly.facets_end(), poly.planes_begin(), Plane_equation());
    CGAL::set_pretty_mode(std::cout);

    for (auto it = poly.planes_begin(); it != poly.planes_end(); ++it) {
      if (isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
        std::cout << "A = " << it->a().exact() << "\n";
        std::cout << "B = " << it->b().exact() << "\n";
        std::cout << "C = " << it->c().exact() << "\n";
        std::cout << "D = " << it->d().exact() << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
      } else {
        std::cout << it->a().exact() << " " << it->b().exact() << " "
                  << it->c().exact() << " " << it->d().exact() << "\n";
      }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, in order to make sure that the generated equations are correct and cover all the points, I create a Z3py script. In that, `f` is the function used to generate the plot, `g` is the conjunction of all plane equations with proper inequality (<, =, >). Then I check if `f ---> g`. I use the theory of reals for infinite precision. But it always comes up with a counter-example. And these counter examples are always on some edge of the plane. Here are a couple of pictures where red circle indicates the location of counterexample. This is a different plot from the one above but the process is the same. Just the input values to `f` is different.

[image: Plot with counterexample 1]

[image: Plot with counterexample 2]

Now, I don't really need infinite precision for my problem. But I would like to make sure that the procedure works with infinite precision so that I can be confident about correctness. But then I tried with CPLEX, which uses only 64-bits, and with that too, counterexamples were generated, in similar fashion to Z3. Here's an example

[image: Plot with CPLEX counterexample]

Now I have no idea in which step of the process am I making a mistake. My suspicion is the selection of initial points for convex hull. It would be great if someone can help me find the convex hull properly. As far as I have read, the convex hull algorithms are exact if infinite precision is used. That's why I didn't use Mathematica's convex hull feature, because it is not using infinite precision.

EDIT: There are two smaller planes which Mathematica is failing to show, as shown below. I want all points on those planes to be selected too. But the endpoints of the smaller planes coincide with the endpoints of larger planes. That's why I have taken only the corners of larger planes.

[image: Smaller planes]

EDIT 2: Due to the range of y being so large compared to the other two variables, the convex hull generated for the above specified points looks just like a single line.

[image: original Convex hull]

However, after diving the y values by 1000, we can see a clearer picture.

[image: smaller convex hull]

Comment: I have not got where something goes wrong.   To take as imput the corners seems correct to me.    Remaining in CGAL, for all planes it should be true that all your grid planes are either on the plane, or all on the positive (or all on the negative)  side.   Did you check that?

Comment: @AndreasFabri Sorry I don't get what you're saying. As I said, I'm a complete newbie. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't see any convex hull among your figures.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Added!

Comment: So what is wrong ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to verify that all points on the above given plot are contained inside the convex hull. I generate the plane equations. Then I use an SMT solver Z3 for checking. However, Z3 can always find a counterexample which is inside the function f but not in the generated convex hull, i.e., a point which should be inside the convex hull, but the equations say it isn't. The red dots in above plots indicate those generated counterexamples.

Comment: Inside the function ? Which function ?

Comment: Mathematica now has a `ConvexHullMesh[]` function. You don't need to use CGAL.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Talking about the function ```f``` which is used to generate this plot. Essentially, I check that every point that can be generated using ```f``` is present inside the convex hull.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke ```ConvexHullMesh``` does not use infinite precision, as far as I know.

Comment: What you say is contradictory. You construct the hull of 8 points but test with other points ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust I construct the hull with 8 extreme points *on* the plot and then test with *all* the points that are *on* the plot. Should I explain in a bit more detail? I understand that there might not be many people working on the intersection of areas that I'm working on so feel free to ask question.

Comment: @SamvidMistry: You are correct. I missed your insistence on infinite precision.

Comment: So you are finding that corners of the convex hull are not inside the hull according to the plane equations?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yes! I tried one thing. I extended the planes in all 4 directions by 0.1. And I've tested it with 2 different plots and it gave me no counter-examples.